# Make text clear form when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make the *EMPTY ALL* text clear out the form when clicked, but I can't figure out how. Please can you help.

### Code

**JavaScript**

```
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

var fragment = create('<div class="someclass"> <p>EMPTY ALL</p></a></div>');

document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="validate_update_inventory">  
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="6" size="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="asin" value="B0073HEMFW">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5063427">
    <input type="hidden" name="referer_action" value="view_inventory_at">                
    <input type="hidden" name="location_name" value="WASTE">
    <input type="hidden" name="maximum_retail_price" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="expiration_date" value="090120">           
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update qty" size="10">            
</form>
```

Comment: Please can you add the form.

Comment: How do I do this? Do I inspect the page and then copy the html code in the body?

Comment: Just to be clear, what exactly does the above code do?

Comment: The code above dynamically added html elements inside div

Comment: `<input type="reset">`?

Comment: `$('.someclass p').addEventListener("click", () => { // form clear });` ?

Comment: just add a `onclick="FUNCTIONNAME()"` to your `p` element and call a function to empty the form (`reset()`)

Comment: I've added the form to post... @GetOffMyLawn I thought I needed to have default values to use the reset function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code targets the forms based on their tag name:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form');
```

then iterates through each form's children, clearing each elements value:

```
Array.from(forms).forEach((form) => {
  Array.from(form.children).forEach((element) => {
    if (element.type != "submit") {
      element.value = '';
    }
  });
});
```

### Full Code

```js
document.body.innerHTML =
  '<button id="clear">EMPTY ALL</button>' +
  document.body.innerHTML;

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener('click', () => {
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  Array.from(forms).forEach((form) => {
    Array.from(form.children).forEach((element) => {
      if (element.type != "submit") {
        element.value = '';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="validate_update_inventory">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="6" size="3">
  <input type="hidden" name="asin" value="B0073HEMFW">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5063427">
  <input type="hidden" name="referer_action" value="view_inventory_at">
  <input type="hidden" name="location_name" value="WASTE">
  <input type="hidden" name="maximum_retail_price" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="expiration_date" value="090120">
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="update qty" size="10">
</form>
```

Comment: Zera - How do I give my form an ID or a class name in the javascript and not in HTML?

Comment: I have modified the code to target the form using its tag name instead of an ID.

Comment: Thank you so much! 2 things - How can I make the EMPTY ALL a button?. Secondly, is it possible to do a mass change? Right now, only the value of the very first item is changing to 0 and there are multiple items on the page that need to have their quantities set to 0.

Comment: You can change `<a>` to `<button>` and the JavaScript SHOULD clear all the items, except the **submit** button.

Comment: Do you have multiple forms?

Comment: Alright, working on the button piece now.. Yes, I have multiple forms with the same form structure as my post

Comment: Much respect, Zera... One more modification is needed, how can I add into the loop to push the ("update qty") button? It seems like I have to do it item by item.. So, input zero for say item 1 > push the "update qty" button, rinse and repeat for other items.

Comment: A `submit` button SHOULD submit all inputs within the current form. I don't know what the issue could be. Maybe there is an issue with the code that you POST the values to.

Comment: I think it isn't submitting because there's a confirmation question (Yes/No to confirm change) that's asked on the very next page. I'm going to make another script for the second page then pass on a parameter and if it's true this script would be called.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript to clear a form, you can justs use the `<input type="reset">` built into html like this:

One catch though, is that you cannot use hidden input types:

```js
const id = document.querySelector('[name=id]')
id.value = 'New Value'

document.querySelector('[type=reset]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(id.value)
})
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="validate_update_inventory">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="6" size="3">
  <input type="text" class="hide" name="asin" value="B0073HEMFW">
  <input type="text" class="hide" name="id" value="5063427">
  <input type="text" class="hide" name="referer_action" value="view_inventory_at">
  <input type="text" class="hide" name="location_name" value="WASTE">
  <input type="text" class="hide" name="maximum_retail_price" value="">
  <input type="text" class="hide" name="expiration_date" value="090120">
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="update qty" size="10">
  <input type="reset" value="Empty All">
</form>
```

If you would prefer to set all items to an empty string (including hidden values):

```js
document.querySelector('#clear').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.parentNode
    .querySelectorAll('[type=text], [type=hidden]')
    .forEach(item => (item.value = ''))
})
```

```html
<form method="post" name="inventory_update" action="validate_update_inventory">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="6" size="3">
  <input type="hidden" name="asin" value="B0073HEMFW">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5063427">
  <input type="hidden" name="referer_action" value="view_inventory_at">
  <input type="hidden" name="location_name" value="WASTE">
  <input type="hidden" name="maximum_retail_price" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="expiration_date" value="090120">
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="update qty" size="10">
  <input type="button" id="clear" value="Empty All">
</form>
```

Comment: Understood.. Will the "Empty All" button clear all the fields for all of the items on the page? There are multiple items on the page

Comment: the above solution doesn't really clear the form it just resets to initial values.  see the js solution below

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started.

```js
function empty(){
var form = document.querySelector('form');

var elements = form.elements;
for(let i = 0;i<elements.length;i++){
   if(elements[i].value != 'submit')elements[i].value='';

}

}
```

```html
<form>

<input type='text'>
<input type='text'>

<input type=submit value='submit'>

</form>

<button onclick='empty()'>empty all</button>
```